# sharedpreferences getting wrong boolean value

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

i would like to create a sharedpreferences for boolean value check, but the value always return false. How to return the correct boolean value for sharedpreferences?

Below is my code

```
  public boolean getBtnState(Context context,String text)//edit to store url here and check the boolean here
{
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String favUrl = getPrefsFavUrl(context);

    boolean switchState = false;

    if(favUrl == text) {
        switchState=true;
    }

    return switchState;//always return false here

}
```

Here is the code to get sharedpreferences value

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        showProgress();
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_favourite);

        Boolean stateBtnNow=sharedPreference.getBtnState(context,mUrl);
         if(stateBtnNow) {
             imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 249, 0, 0));//red
         }
        else
         {
             imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 192, 192, 192));
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two `String` variables with `==` operator instead use `.equals()` method.

```
if(favUrl.equals(text)) {
    switchState=true;
}
```

it will work.

Refer [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion) for `==` and `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(favUrl.equals(text)){
    switchState = true;
}
```

instead of

```
if(favUrl == text) {
    switchState=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to:

```
public boolean getBtnState(Context context,String text) { //edit to store url here and check the boolean here
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return getPrefsFavUrl(context).equals(text); // fixed and simplified code
}
```